# KeyError: '!button2' Tkinter button error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When I try to create a button in a tkinter window, I get an error that I couldn't fix. I spent 5 hours on this button and didn't solve the problem.

error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 1070, in cmd
    self.cnf['command']() if self.cnf.get('command') else None
  File "/Users/alina/PycharmProjects/App/pagame.py", line 113, in build_settings
    self.button2 = Button(self.settings_root, text='text')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/widget.py", line 90, in __init__
    tkb.ButtonBase.__init__(self, master=master, cnf=cnf, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 1200, in __init__
    self._configure1(self.cnf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 922, in _configure1
    self._set_configure(self._get_options(opt, kw))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 798, in _get_options
    if self._mouse_state_condition() and self.cnf.get('overbackground'):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 369, in _mouse_state_condition
    con2 = bool(self.winfo_containing(*self.winfo_pointerxy()) == self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1064, in winfo_containing
    return self._nametowidget(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1498, in nametowidget
    w = w.children[n]
KeyError: '!button2'
```

i tried using:

```
ttk.Button
```

and

```
Button(image=img)
button.image = img
```

But it did not help.

my full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

system = 'macos'  # other
if system == 'macos':
    from tkmacosx import Button
else:
    from tkinter import Button


def open_img(path, size=(30, 30)):
    image = Image.open(path)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    return image


class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.listbox = 'listbox'
        self.backgrounds = {'dark': '#333',
                            'light': 'white'}
        self.background_ = 'dark'
        self.lang = 'en'
        self.last_win = '700x500'
        self.build_loading_root()

    @property
    def theme(self):
        pass

    @theme.setter
    def theme(self, value):
        self.background_ = self.backgrounds[value]

    @theme.getter
    def theme(self):
        return self.backgrounds[self.background_]

    def change_lang(self, event):
        self.root.destroy()
        if self.listbox.get() == ' English ':
            self.lang = 'en'
        elif self.listbox.get() == ' Русский ':
            self.lang = 'ru'
        self.build_loading_root()

    def main_screen(self):
        self.root_main = tk.Tk()
        self.root_main.title('trading selector')
        self.root_main['bg'] = self.theme
        self.root_main.geometry(self.last_win)
        self.root.bind('<Configure>', self.win_checker)
        self.root_main.mainloop()

    def win_checker(self, event):
        width, heigth = event.width, event.height
        self.last_win = f'{event.width}x{event.height}'
        if self.last_win == '233x54' or width*heigth < 90_000:
            self.last_win = '700x500'
        print(self.last_win)

    def build_loading_root(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("quick_trade")
        self.root.geometry(self.last_win)
        self._language = 'Language:' if self.lang == 'en' else 'Язык:'
        self.root.configure(background=self.theme)
        self.screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        # logo
        img = open_img('qutr.PNG', size=(self.screen_width // 3,
                                         round(self.screen_height // 3 / 1.5)))
        label = tk.Label(self.root, image=img,
                         bd=0, bg=self.theme)
        label.pack()

        # continue
        img_lang_continue = open_img('rus_continue.PNG' if self.lang == 'ru' else 'eng_continue.PNG', (200, 50))
        label2 = Button(self.root, image=img_lang_continue, bd=0, command=self.main_screen,
                        bg=self.backgrounds[self.background_])
        label2.pack(side='bottom', expand=self.screen_height // 10)

        # settings
        im3 = open_img('settings_icon.PNG' if self.theme == 'light' else 'setting_white.PNG', (40, 40))
        label3 = Button(self.root, image=im3, bd=0, command=self.build_settings, bg=self.theme)
        label3.place(x=self.screen_width - 70, y=0)
        self.root.bind('<Configure>', self.win_checker)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def build_settings(self):

        self.settings_root = tk.Tk()
        self.settings_root.title('settings')
        self.settings_root.geometry(self.last_win)
        self.settings_root['bg'] = self.theme
        self.labelx = tk.Label(self.settings_root, text=self._language, bg=self.theme,
                               fg=self.backgrounds['light' if self.background_ == 'dark' else 'dark'])

        self.listbox = ttk.Combobox(self.settings_root, height=123, textvariable=tk.StringVar())
        self.listbox['values'] = (' English ',
                                  ' Русский ')
        self.listbox.current(0 if self.lang == 'en' else 1)
        self.listbox.place(x=100, y=60)
        self.listbox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.change_lang)
        self.settings_root.bind('<Configure>', self.win_checker)
        self.listbox.current()
        self.labelx.place(x=30, y=60)

        self.button2 = Button(self.settings_root, text='text')
        self.button2.place()
        self.settings_root.mainloop()

app = App()
```

I work with mac os x (catalina) OS.
Perhaps the error is that I create and delete windows using a strange system, but I cannot imagine another implementation option if it is impossible to clear the window of its widgets.

Comment: Your using multiple instance of `Tk()` which is not recommended, change extra or child windows to `Toplevel()`

Comment: **Your code is working fine on my mac without any errors.** I'm also using `tkmacosx 0.1.4` and `python3.8.3`, try updating to that version and if that doesn't help, please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64001242/edit) your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)